# Is it safe to block redirected (but still linked) URLs with robots.txt?

Tags: seo, google, url, robots.txt, search-engine-indexing

I have a website that has all URLs optimized and 301 redirected from nasty URLs to clean ones. However, everywhere throughout the site the unclean URLs are linked in menus, content, products, etc. Google currently has all clean URLs indexed, along with a few unclean URLs too.

So the site still has linked everywhere the old URLs (ideally this wouldn't be the case but this is how it is ATM).

I would like to block the unclean URLs with *robots.txt*.

The question: if I block these unclean URLs with the *robots.txt*, when the entire website is linked with them (but they all redirect to the clean version), will this affect the indexing status at all?

Answer (score 4):

If you disallow the unclean URLs in robots.txt, polite bots will no longer visit these URLs. So they will never notice that you 301-redirect them to other URLs that they’d be allowed to crawl. Bots that don’t know your clean URLs yet would only be able to visit these pages when they are directly linked to with the clean variant (not the blocked unclean variant).

So you should **not** block them in robots.txt.

As you are 301-redirecting your unclean URLs to corresponding clean URLs, you don’t need to do anything. Bots will know what to do. If some search engines still have some unclean URLs indexed, it should only be a matter of time until they update their index.

Answer (score 0):

There's no to need to block anything in *robots.txt* these days, simple use `rel="canonical"` on your pages and you never risk duplicate pages regardless if its accessible via unclean or clean because the canonical will tell Google the preferred.

In regards of the indexed non-clean URLs if you use canonical's these will deindex/update themselves however if you don't have page replacements and you just want to remove them then using both `noindex` in your head *HTML* and `disallow: /unclean-url/` in your *robots.txt* (Google recommends both *robots.txt* and `noindex` usage).

Also for SEO purposes you should correct those URLs as soon as possible as your losing page juice due through the 301 redirect.

Comment: Ok thanks, but do you think it will affect the site or not? I'm working with a Budget and there are limits to what I can do ATM. Thanks.

Comment: How would the Googlebot stumble upon `noindex`, when it isn’t allowed to crawl the page in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The redirection won't work on those blocked URLs. After adding 301 redirection you will not need to apply canonical as well. This won't effect the websites I have seen big brands changing the URL and make millions of redirection just like the SEOmoz did after changing its name to Moz.